# Can't locate build.xml file when running ant through a shell script

Tags: bash, ant, cygwin

I'm using bash shell running on Cygwin on Windows 7.  I have this in my bash script, which attempts to figure out the location of a build file based on the location of the currently executing script …

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
BUILDFILE=$SCRIPT_DIR/build.xml
ant -buildfile $BUILDFILE -Dbuildtarget=$1 -Dmodule="$2" -Dproject=$3 -Dnolabel=true -DFirefox=$4 -DInternetExplorer=$5 -DGoogleChrome=$6 Selenium4
```

However, even though the file is there, I get an "Unable to locate buildfile error"

```
$ sh c:/selenium//run_client_tests.sh prod "\Critical Path\Live\QX" MyProj true false false
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: c:/selenium//run_client_tests.sh
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/selenium/run_client_tests.sh
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Started script
Buildfile: \cygdrive\c\selenium\build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

ls reveals the file is there …

```
dev@selenium_w7 /cygdrive/c/selenium
$ ls /cygdrive/c/selenium/build.xml
/cygdrive/c/selenium/build.xml

dev@selenium_w7 /cygdrive/c/selenium
$ ls c:/selenium/build.xml
c:/selenium/build.xml
```

Comment: Any chance you're winding up with DOS `\r\n' line-endings in your script file? I can't remember, does Cygwin deal with that graciously? Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that ant does not know about Cygwin-style paths.  Note that ant is complaining that it cannot find \cygdrive\c\selenium\build.xml.  That is because /cygwin is only understood by the Cygwin shell.

What you need to do is pass a DOS-style path to ant.  So replace

```
BUILDFILE=$SCRIPT_DIR/build.xml
```

with

```
BUILDFILE=`cygpath -w $SCRIPT_DIR/build.xml`
```

Or to make this a bit more platform-agnostic, use Java-style paths

```
BUILDFILE=`cygpath -m $SCRIPT_DIR/build.xml`
```